# Requires user session error while using FQL in facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I am making a fb app and this is what I need to do:

I get the page id of a business page and I need to get the admin_id of the page. I am using the following code and I get the error message which I have copied at the end.

Can anyone kindly help me ? Thanks.

```
include_once 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook($api_key, $secret);

//$page_ids == page_id of a business/fan page  

$query="SELECT uid from page_admin where page_id =".$page_ids.";";

$admins =$facebook->api_client->fql_query($query);

foreach ($admins as $jerry) {
  echo $jerry['uid']."<br>";
}
```

error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'FacebookRestClientException' with message 'Requires user session' in /var/www/seanpeace/data/www/racersnation.com/facebookTest/facebookapi_php5_restlib.php:3112 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/seanpeace/data/www/racersnation.com/facebookTest/facebookapi_php5_restlib.php(1025): FacebookRestClient->call_method('facebook.fql.qu...', Array) #1 /var/www/seanpeace/data/www/racersnation.com/facebookTest/profile.php(64): FacebookRestClient->fql_query('SELECT uid from...') #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/seanpeace/data/www/racersnation.com/facebookTest/facebookapi_php5_restlib.php on line 3112
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Problem while executing Facebook query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081206/problem-while-executing-facebook-query)

the answer is provided here,

we need to write the following lines...

$facebook = new Facebook($api_key, $secret);
$facebook = $facebook->require_login();
$facebook = $facebook->require_frame();

thanks :)

Comment: Note that these methods don't exist anymore, and therefore aren't the fix, if you're using the Facebook PHP SDK greater than 3.0.