# Multiple integration sources of Facebook apps; "Requires user session" exception

Tags: php, ios, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm writing a test application on iPhone with API backend. Application uses Facebook SDK.
I ask for permissions, receive them properly.
Then I ask from iPhone app my API backend to query Facebook with FQL for users that uses same app that I do.

My API connects to Facebook with Facebook PHP SDK, but can't receive any data since it is catching an exception:

> "Requires user session".

I use single Facebook application with "Native iOS App" and "Website with Facebook Login" checked.
("Website with Facebook Login" has Site URL filled with my API URL).

Could you please tell me what is the problem here?

Diagram below (error at (3)):

[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following lines:

```
$facebook = new Facebook($api_key, $secret); $facebook = $facebook->require_login();
$facebook = $facebook->require_frame();
```

**References:**

[Problem while executing Facebook query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081206/problem-while-executing-facebook-query)

[Requires user session error while using FQL in facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174938/requires-user-session-error-while-using-fql-in-facebook)

Comment: Hi Ivo. I've tried your referenced solutions before posting this question. Knowing Facebook's API a bit I nearly always skip solutions that are older than 6 months.. 
Facebook just mix with their API so much..

Comment: Ahh, Facebook Docs are so terrible. One suggestion, if you have Facebook, join this group: https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/ Referring to your question, what does print_r of $facebook shows up?

Comment: `object(Facebook)[61]
  protected 'sharedSessionID' => null
  protected 'appId' => string 'myappid' (length=15)
  protected 'appSecret' => string 'myappsecret' (length=32)
  protected 'user' => null
  protected 'signedRequest' => null
  protected 'state' => null
  protected 'accessToken' => string 'myappid|myappsecret' (length=48)
  protected 'fileUploadSupport' => boolean false
  protected 'trustForwarded' => boolean false`

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving `"Requires user session"`, because I wasn't passing user's access_token to API call.

To solve this problem you obviously have to add access_token received from Facebook.